# Question about Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the following things in my hand 
$\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ ,an algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ which is given by $F_0$=$(a_1,b_1]\cup(a_2,b_2]\cup.........\cup(a_n,b_n]$
I know that the measure defined on $F_0$ is $\mu_0$=$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(b_i-a_i)$, and by caratheodory extension theorem, we can extend this measure to measure a sigma-algebra generated by $F_0$ say $\sigma(F_0)$ known as a Lebesgue measure say $\mu$
Now I have proved using the above that $\mu\{a\}$=0 i.e Lebesgue measure of a singleton is 0, now I want to prove that  $\mu((a,b))=b-a$,for singleton $a$ I expressed it as $\mu({a})$=$\mu(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(b-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n}))$ then I used continuity of measure to get the answer as 0,but I am having problem to express $(a,b)$ in such form.

Comment: yes ,thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: $(a,b)=\bigcup_n(a,b-1/n]$.

Comment: Another way to prove that $\mu((a,b))=b-a$.  Note that  $\mu((a,b])=b-a$ (by definition) and you have already proved that $\mu(\{b\})=0$, so we have:
$$ b-a = \mu((a,b]) = \mu((a,b)) + \mu(\{b\}) = \mu((a,b)) + 0 = \mu((a,b)) $$